# React select styling

Tags: javascript, react-select, chakra-ui

[image]

I'm using the chakra-react-select@3.3.8.

What I want to achieve is to set the multiValue style dynamically based on whether the select element is focused or not.
My issue is I did not find a way to access this state value.

Basically when I press the tab and select gains focus I want to change the color of the multiValue (tag) element.

Please note I want to apply the style if the select element gains focused not if the multiValue element gains focus, which is already available in the second argument of the state function.

```
  multiValue: (provided, state) => {
    const styles = isSelectFocused ? multiValueFocusedStyle : multiValueFocused;

    return {
      ...provided,
      ...styles,
    };
  },
```

Something like this is close to what I want to achieve but it's not good enough for me:

```
  multiValue: (provided, state) => {
    isSelectFocused = state.selectProps.menuIsOpen
```

To summarize, is there a way to access the state, whether the select element is focused or not from within the style function?

Answer (score 0):

This works but I feel like there should be an easier solution:

```
{ onFocus, onBlur, ...rest }: ReactSelectProps<Option, IsMulti, Group>,
const [isSelectFocused, setIsSelectFocused] = React.useState(false);
```

And in the rendered react select:

```
  <ReactSelectComponent
    onFocus={(event) => {
      setIsSelectFocused(true);
      onFocus?.(event);
    }}
    onBlur={(event) => {
      setIsSelectFocused(false);
      onBlur?.(event);
    }}
    {...rest}
  />
```